# Key words and sum equations

Tags: excel

[Sample Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0lQ2.jpg) I have a spreadsheet That I am having trouble getting a formula running. 
I have a table that has a handful of columns, being brand, description and sales.
I need to get a formula that will automatically find a keyword in column A and B and SUM all the totals to transfer to another worksheet.

Example I have 2 similar products by name, Demo Firm, and Demo Soft. I have them sorted into text to columns to make it easier to search. Demo in the 1st Column, Firm in the 2nd, Sales in the 3rd.

I need to be able to search all of column A and find every word "DEMO", then I need the formula to Search Colum B and Find all the "Firm", finally I need it to sum up the totals of Column 3 of "DEMO FIRM" and place the sum into Column4.

I have tried IFSUM, IFSUMS, and DSUM but I think I am missing one little step.

I hope this makes sense, in my head I know what I want to do, explaining it is difficult.

Thanks for your help. Will keep an eye on my email if further info needed.

I have uploaded an image of what I am needing (SAMPLE PAGE at top of post). The formula that was commented worked for a my small sample. I just need to make sure it will work on an ever changing spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry guys, In the 3rd paragraph, I only need the 2nd column to find firm IF colum one finds Demo as there will be multiple products running Firm, Soft etc...

Comment: You can just edit your own question. No need to put a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is assumed that your data fills rows 2-10, i.e. `A2:A10`, etc., but obviously this can be changed as needed. As I understand it, you want to sum up all sales into Column D, based on the values in Column A and Column B. You can simply use a `SUMIFS` formula in Column D, in this case `D2` and drag down for all rows, as follows:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$10, $A$2:$A$10, A2, $B$2:$B$10, B2)
```

So if `A2` contains DEMO and `B2` contains FIRM, then this formula will sum all of the sales totals in Column C where Column A contains DEMO **and** Column B contains FIRM.